# Exclude some specific categories from search on wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I am using some categories for gallery images and some information about user, i don't want that categories showed in search result on wordpress

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function SearchFilter($query) 
{   
    if( $query->is_search && ! is_admin() )
    {    
       $query->set('cat','8,15');   
    }  
    return $query; 
} 
add_filter('pre_get_posts','SearchFilter');
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this code to functions.php

```
 function searchfilter($query) {
  if ($query->is_search && !is_category('specific-category-slug') ) {
    $query->set('post_type',array('post','page'));
  }
  return $query;
}
add_filter('pre_get_posts','searchfilter');
```

Change the "*specific-category-slug*" of is_category('specific-category-slug') with that category slug which you want to exclude.

Comment: Yes thanks @aryan, i just got the answer  `function SearchFilter($query) {
  if ( $query->is_search && ! is_admin() ) {
    $query->set('cat','8,15'); 
  }
  return $query; `
}
add_filter('pre_get_posts','SearchFilter');

Answer (score 0):

```
function wcs_exclude_category_search( $query ) {
    if ( is_admin() || ! $query->is_main_query() )
        return;

    if ( $query->is_search ) {
        $query->set( 'cat', '-22, -21' );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wcs_exclude_category_search', 1 );
```

Comment: Please use category id in $query->set( 'cat', '-22, -21' ); separated by comma

Comment: if you don't want to use code  then use this plugin.https://wordpress.org/plugins/search-exclude/